# object oriented Java, arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm trying to create a program to facilitate the registration of customer profiles, and bank account but deposits and withdrawals.

My problem now is that I can not implement the deposits when the index variable gets the wrong value. It does not find the value that the code searches for and returns thus -1.

My question is whether anyone could help me, tell me where the error is. 
I'm very new to programming in Java on desire not to receive messages get whiny comments. I ask because I want to learn more. So please come with tips and suggestions, and explanations.

Thanks in advance =)

**Menu.java**

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package bank;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Menu {

    int val = 0;
    int user = 0;
    Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public void printMenu() {
        while (val != 10) {
        System.out.println("----------------------------");
        System.out.println("1. Lägg till kund");
        System.out.println("2. Redigera kunduppgifter");
        System.out.println("3. Ta bort kund");
        System.out.println("----------------------------");
        System.out.println("4. Nytt konto(befintlig kund)");
        System.out.println("5. Ta bort konto");
        System.out.println("----------------------------");
        System.out.println("6. Visa alla kunder");
        System.out.println("----------------------------");
        System.out.println("7. Insättning");
        System.out.println("8. Uttag");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.print("Ditt val: ");

        //Fångar upp användarens val
        try{
            val = user_input.nextInt();
            if(val>10){ System.out.println("Meny finns inte"); }
        }catch(java.util.InputMismatchException e){
            System.out.println("Felaktig inmatning");
        }
        //Returnerar val
        menuAction(val);
        }
    }

    public void menuAction(int val){
        BankLogic BL = new BankLogic();


            //Switch som bytar metod beroende på val
            switch (val) {
                case 1:
                    System.out.print("Ange kundens förnamn: ");
                    String fName = user_input.next();
                    System.out.print("Ange kundens efternamn: ");
                    String lName = user_input.next();
                    System.out.print("Ange personnummer: ");
                    long perNR = user_input.nextLong();
                    System.out.print("Ange startkapital: ");
                    int deposit = user_input.nextInt();

                    String name = fName + " " + lName;
                    BL.addCustomer(name, perNR, deposit);

                    break;

                case 2:
                    System.out.print("Ange personnummer: ");
                    long ID = user_input.nextLong();
                    BL.infoCustomer(ID);
                    break;

                case 3:
                    System.out.print("Ange kundens personnummer: ");
                    ID = user_input.nextLong();
                    BL.removeCustomer(ID);

                    break;

                case 4:
                    System.out.print("Ange kundens personnummer: ");
                    ID = user_input.nextLong();
                    BL.addSavingsAccount(ID);
                    break;

                case 5:
                    System.out.print("Ange kundens personnummer: ");
                    ID = user_input.nextLong();
                    System.out.print("Ange det kontonr som skall tas bort: ");
                    int ACCNR = user_input.nextInt();
                    BL.closeAccount(ID, ACCNR);
                    break;

                case 6:
                    BL.infoBank();
                    break;

                case 7:
                    System.out.print("Ange kundens personnummer: ");
                    long pernr = user_input.nextLong();
                    System.out.print("Ange kundens kontonummer: ");
                    int acc = user_input.nextInt();
                    System.out.print("Ange kundens instättningsbelopp: ");
                    double amount = user_input.nextDouble();                    
                    BL.deposit(pernr, acc, amount);
                    break;
                case 8:
                    System.out.print("Ange kundens personnummer: ");
                    ID = user_input.nextLong();
                    System.out.print("Ange kontonr: ");
                    ACCNR = user_input.nextInt();
                    System.out.print("Ange belopp: ");
                    amount = user_input.nextInt();

                    BL.withdraw(ID, ACCNR, amount);

                    break;

                case 9:
                    System.out.println("Loggar ut!");
                    break;
            }
    }

}
```

**Customer.java**

```
    /*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package bank;

import java.util.ArrayList;


//###### CUSTOMER ######
class Customer{
    String name;
    long ID;
    int accounts;

    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> fullList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

    public boolean addCustomer(String name, long ID, int deposit){
        SavingsAccount SA = new SavingsAccount();
        String ACCNR = String.valueOf(SA.generateAccountNr());
        String id = String.valueOf(ID);

        String Deposit = String.valueOf(deposit);

        list.add(id);
        list.add(name);
        list.add(ACCNR);
        list.add(Deposit);
        fullList.add(list);
        System.out.println("Kund lades till");

        return true;
    }

    public boolean editCustomer(String newName, long ID){
        int index = fullList.indexOf(ID);
        fullList.get(index).set(3, newName);
        return true;
    }
    public boolean deleteCustomer (long ID){
        int index = fullList.indexOf(ID);
        fullList.remove(index);

        return true;
    }

    public String showCustomer(long ID){
        int index = fullList.indexOf(ID);

        System.out.println("Kontonummer \t Name \t Personnummer \t ");
        for(ArrayList<String> r: fullList){
            System.out.print(r.get(index) + "\t");
        }
        System.out.print("");
        return null;
    }

    public String showCustomers(){
        System.out.println("Kontonummer \t Name \t Personnummer \t ");
        for(ArrayList<String> r : fullList){
            for(int i = 0; i < r.size(); i++){
                System.out.print(r.get(i) + "\t");
            }
        }
        return null;
    }


}
```

**SavingsAccount.java**

```
    /*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package bank;

//###### SAVINGACCOUNT ######
class SavingsAccount {
    int AccNr = 1000;
    double saldo = 0;
    int intrest = 2;

    Customer CR = new Customer();

    public int generateAccountNr(){
        AccNr++;
        return AccNr;
    }

    public void newSavingAcc(long ID){
        int index = CR.fullList.indexOf(ID);

        String ACCNR = String.valueOf(generateAccountNr());
        CR.fullList.get(index).add(ACCNR);
    }

    public void deposit(long ID, int accNr, double amount){
        //String id = String.valueOf(ID);

        int index = CR.fullList.indexOf("ID");
        System.out.print("Detta är INDEX: " + index);

        saldo = saldo + amount;

        String balance = String.valueOf(saldo);
        CR.fullList.get(index).set(2, balance);

    }

    public void withdraw(long ID, int withdraw){

        int index = CR.fullList.indexOf(ID);
        String id = String.valueOf(index);

        saldo = saldo - withdraw;

        String balance = String.valueOf(saldo);
        CR.fullList.get(index).set(2, balance);
    }

    public double intrest (long ID, int saldo){
        int index = CR.fullList.indexOf(ID);

        double decSaldo = saldo; 
        decSaldo = decSaldo * (intrest/100);

        String stopBalance = String.valueOf(saldo);
        CR.fullList.get(index).set(2, stopBalance);

        return decSaldo;
    }

}
```

**BankLogic**

```
    /*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package bank;


//###### BankLogic ######
public class BankLogic {

    Customer CR = new Customer();
    SavingsAccount SA = new SavingsAccount();

    public String infoBank(){

        return null;
    }

    public boolean addCustomer(String name, long pNr, int deposit){
        CR.addCustomer(name, pNr, deposit);
        CR.showCustomers();
        return true;
    }

    public String infoCustomer(long pNr){
        CR.showCustomer(pNr);
        return null;
    }

    public boolean changeCustomerName(String name, long pNr){
        CR.editCustomer(name, pNr);
        return true;
    }

    public String removeCustomer(long pNr){
        CR.deleteCustomer(pNr);   
        return null;
    }

    public int addSavingsAccount(long pNr){
        SA.newSavingAcc(pNr);
        return 0;
    }

    public String infoAccount(long pNr, int accountId){

        return null;
    }

    public boolean deposit(long pNr, int accountId, double amount){
        SA.deposit(pNr, accountId, amount);
        return true;
    }

    public boolean withdraw(long pNr, int accountId, double amount){


        return true;
    }

    public String closeAccount(long pNr, int accountId){

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: In which class you face error.4 classes making difficult to find issue

Comment: Sorry, my bad. In SavingsAccount, method deposit

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve with emphasis to *minimal*

Comment: Can you explain better what's the problem? The program is not doing what you want or it's giving some error?

Comment: I think the best thing you could do would be to learn to use a debugger.  It's an absolutely vital tool for any programmer.

Comment: I'm not trying to be rude,but if you want more people to attempt and fix your code,you should clarify your problem (which i didn't understand) and try to narrow the location of your problem by posting only snaps of code that are relevant to the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the line that says

```
int index = CR.fullList.indexOf("ID");
```

to

```
int index = CR.fullList.indexOf(ID);
```

Otherwise you're looking for the actual letters "ID" as the identifier.

Comment: same problem despite the change

Comment: Did you intend to search `list` or `fullList`?  I'm a little confused over which is which.  Why is `fullList` an `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>`?

Comment: I try to make the list multidimensional. Therefore, I have an array list of array list

Comment: But why?  Anyway, if you really need that list to be multi-dimensional (for whatever reason), I guess you'll need to search each internal list individually.

Comment: Perhaps I make it harder than what it is? Perhaps there is a better solution? I need a list that can store personal information, account numbers - with balance. Then I shall be able to add new account (account number) to "personal profile".

Comment: Yes.  You've made it harder than it is, by having a multi-dimensional list.  I still don't understand why you want that.

Comment: It's not that I WANT to have it. It's about my ignorance and I thought I NEEDED it ;) So I'm open to suggestions and would welcome another solution =)

Comment: You should make a Class Customer that has personal information,account numbers and balance as data members if those attributes are related to a customer. Than you can make an ArrayList of Customer objects.

Comment: A `HashMap<String,Customer>` might work well, since a lot of operations involve starting with a customer id.